# Flex mobile: display back button automatically if view is not first in stack

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, flex-mobile

In Flex 4.5 for mobile is it possible to check if there is > 1 view on a navigation stack and display a back button accordingly? If so how can I do this?

My application is based on

```
  s:ViewNavigatorApplication
```

I'm adding a back button like this

```
  <s:navigationContent>
    <s:Button label="Back" click="backButtonPressed(event)"/>
  </s:navigationContent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your view you should be able to do something like this:

```
if(navigator.firstView == this){
  Back.visible = false;
} else {
  Back.visible = true;
}
```

More info on [firstView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/ViewNavigator.html#firstView) property.  You may consider running that code in a [viewActivate](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/View.html#event%3aviewActivate) handler on the view.  Or possibly during the view creation lifecycle startup, using the initialize event.

Comment: Thanks! I guess to make this generic I could put it in a view superclass that I inherit from. Do you also know if and how I could subclass ViewNavigator to encapsulate the same behaviour?

Comment: I dunno what you need to know, really.  Just subclass the ViewNavigator.  Add your back button as part of the navigation content.  Add that code in there somehow.  Extend the View class to use your new custom ViewNavigator class.  You'd have to pour over the framework code for specifics.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to handle such behaviors in the Back Button:

set in your button component: enabled="{navigator.selectedIndex!=0}"

I think binding looks much better, and easier to maintain.

Comment: There isn't a navigator.selectedIndex property for a ViewNavigator.

Comment: I think I would have to use visible="{classOf(navigator.activeView) != navigator.firstView}" to make the back button disappear completely. I have another problem with my solution of creating a superclass view in that states can only be created in the base view. This means that if I create a base view containing the back button functionality I can't make use of portrait / landscape states in the derived view.

Comment: Sorry that I don't have experience in flex mobile app, so did give you a defective answer. I'm not pretty sure about your question, why can't derived view has states? Derived view can bind its states to the base view's, or vice versa.

Comment: Could you give me a code snippet showing how I could make my derived view bind its states to the base views states?

Comment: In the derived view, <fx:Binding source="(parent as BaseType).currentState" destination="this.currentState"/>

Answer (score 0):

at least in flex 4.6, this procedure can be made like this:

```
<s:Button label="Back" visible="{navigator.length>1}"/>
```